# How to show the equivalence between these two definitions of an ordered field?

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, ordered-fields

Definition 1: A field $F$ is an order field if

a) $x,y,z\in F,y \lt z \to x + y \lt x + z$

b) $x,y\in F, x \gt 0, y \gt 0 \to xy \gt 0$

Definition 2: A field $F$ is called an ordered field if there exists $P \in F$ s.t.

a) $x,y \in P \to x+y \in P, xy \in P$

b) $x \in F\to x \in P$ or $x=0$ or $-x\in P$

I think a logical path would be to use the properties of a field to derive the set P from the conditions in definition 1. However, I'm not really sure if that is entirely correct or even how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: "$P$" stands for "positive numbers".

Comment: @MJD I understand that part, but I'm still not sure where to go. I currently still trying to find an answer based off of Hayden's hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: For the implication $(1) \implies (2)$, show that the set $P=\{x \in F \mid x>0\}$ gives you what you want in $(2)$.

For the implication $(2) \implies (1)$, define $<$ by saying that $x<y$ if $y-x \in P$, then show that $<$ is a strict total order which satisfies the conditions of $(1)$.

To understand the intuition, the idea is that $P$ is the set of positive elements.

(Also, strictly speaking, in definition $(2)$ the set $P$ should be supplied from the get-go (in the same way $<$ is provided in definition $(1)$).  Otherwise I'd say that $F$ isn't ordered, but is *orderable* since a priori there's no reason to suspect $P$ is unique.)

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. It seems like $2 \to 1$ might be easier. However, I'm not really sure how you could confirm the properties of definition 1. Could you elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Suppose $y<z$, so $y-z \in P$ by definition.  Then $y-z=(y+x)-(z+x) \in P$, so...